# grab serialized data from sql

Tags: php, sql, serialization, foreach

I want to grab the unserialized data from sql, but it only shows the first line. What is wrong?

```
$cars=unserialize($rows["cars"]);
foreach($cars as $car)
{
  echo "<li>".$car."</li>";
}
```

The field in the SQL Table looks like this:

```
a:2:{s:6:"car";s:9:"mercedes";s:6:"ps";s:46:"120";}
a:2:{s:6:"car";s:7:"audi";s:6:"ps";s:74:"145";}
```

Comment: What language is that?  Its sure not SQL.

Comment: Only the first line is returned. Its php and I get the data from a mysql table. I use xampp by the way...

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($rows["cars"]);`?

Comment: and what RDBMS are you using? MySql?

Comment: $res=mysql_query("SELECT cars.id, cars.cars, WHERE cars.id=".$id);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($res);

Comment: Kind of missing the `FROM` clause (not sure if that's your actual code). But anyway, do a `var_dump($rows["cars"]);` before the loop and post the output please

Comment: I tried this, but also not working as it should...

Edited the the data to grab:

      a:2:{s:6:"car";s:9:"mercedes";s:6:"ps";s:46:"120";}<br>
      a:2:{s:6:"car";s:7:"audi";s:6:"ps";s:74:"145";}

And here I edited the foreach loop:

    $cars=explode("<br>", $rows["cars"]);
    foreach($cars as $car)
    {
      echo "<li>".unserialize($car)."</li>";
    }

Comment: I just posted wrong. In my real script i do have the from  paramter.

Comment: I tried this, but also not working: $cars=explode("<br>", $rows["cars"]);

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I can't unless you give me the info I asked for. Sorry.

Comment: I appreciate very much your help. I already solved the problem. Thanks anyway. I complety removed the serializing function...

Comment: Cool. Mind deleting the post?

Answer (score 0):

at first your serialized strings are not valid:
a:2:{s:3:"car";s:8:"mercedes";s:2:"ps";s:3:"120";}
a:2:{s:3:"car";s:4:"audi";s:2:"ps";s:3:"145";}
are correct.

Second:

You cant concat these values and do unserialize like in this NOT WORKING example:

```
unserialize('a:2:{s:3:"car";s:8:"mercedes";s:2:"ps";s:3:"120";}a:2:{s:3:"car";s:4:"audi";s:2:"ps";s:3:"145";}');
```

This will return only the first entry.
You now have to options:
1. split that string before hand by a line break or write it correct to the database as one serialized string. As it would be:

```
var_dump(serialize(array(array('car'=>'mercedes', 'ps' => '120'), array('car'=>'audi', 'ps' => '145'))));
string(110) "a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:3:"car";s:8:"mercedes";s:2:"ps";s:3:"120";}i:1;a:2:{s:3:"car";s:4:"audi";s:2:"ps";s:3:"145";}}"
```

Update:
Sorry didnt saw the "8 more comments link"